# Copy columns from one excel sheet to another with different formatting

Tags: excel, vba

I have 5 sheets in my Excel file. Out of these 5, one is the master sheet which has all the data I want to copy to the other 4 sheets.
All the sheets have one common column, ID. The master has more than 10000 IDs.

What I want to do is:

If ID in sheet1 = 24356 = ID in master sheet then copy x, y, z columns from master sheet to sheet1. This is same for all other sheets.

Also, since the master sheet is from other source than the rest of the sheets, its formatting is different. Is there a way to remove all formatting in sheets before running copy/paste?

Can anyone please tell me the VBA code to do this.

This is how my Master sheet looks like:
[image]
I want the other sheet (eg sheet1) in this case to look like:
[image]

Is it possible to do this without entering a lookup formula in every cell?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, I don't think you actually need to use a macro for this.
Let's say that your MasterSheet is something like:

[image]

and your various sheets have the IDs in column A:

[image]

You could put this in B1:

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP($A1,MasterSheet!$A:$D,2,FALSE)),"",VLOOKUP($A1,MasterSheet!$A:$D,2,FALSE))
```

then simply increment the VLOOKUP's return column for each other column:

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP($A1,MasterSheet!$A:$D,**3**,FALSE)),"",VLOOKUP($A1,MasterSheet!$A:$D,**3**,FALSE))
```

Result:

[image]

You should probably use a better/quicker formula for the lookup to see if the ID exists (like Match)...

Hope this helps.

Cheers,

iso

Comment: @ Isotrope: Thanks so much. This worked perfectly fine. The only questions I have is we have so many ID's in excel sheet and these keeps on increasing every month. Can you suggest me something which is a permenent solution without adding macros in every cells as there as many columns. Also since the master sheet is from different sourec, its formatting is always messed up. Is there a way to remove all formatting from all sheets (like formating all variables to numeric etc..) I would appreciate your response. Thanks

Comment: You could try replacing the increment with column():    =IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP($A1,MasterSheet!$A:$D,COLUMN(),FALSE)),"",VLOOKUP($A1,MasterSheet!$A:$D,COLUMN(),FALSE)) or something like column() + and increment... that way, you should be able to apply it across the board. As for the number of values/IDs, you shouldn't have a problem since it'll always look through the whole column (no specific row range defined).   It would help if you could show us a sample document

Comment: @ Isotrope: Thanks! I have an example in my question above. Since I dont want to copy all columns from master sheet into other sheets, the formula is not letting me skip columns. Is there a way to do this without adding formula in all cells and copying only columns which I want and not all.